# Angular control flow of components dynamically based on user input

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and have an Angular 10 app that I am working on.

Due to regulations I have to display a series of questions, 1 question at a time.  Based on how the user answers, the next question will display, or it will stop and display a page, saying something like *can't process request*.

Here is my problem. Initially the user answers 3 questions and based on those answers I need to used one of five question flows. I used `router.navigate(['']), {state: { parm: parm } });` and navigated to one of the five components. Once I am there, I am not sure what to do next. Within each of the component there can be 3 different sets of questions depending on the `parm` passed in. I could hardcode them, but maintaining that would be a nightmare.

I did a lot of researching into dynamic routing, activating routes, but none of them seemed to meet my needs. Is there something else I should be looking at?

Sorry added more info.

Here is what I was thinking I might be able to do.  I was thinking I could use a chain of responsibility pattern.

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';
import { Handler } from '../../shared/interfaces/handler.interface';
import { AbstractHandler } from '../../shared/services/handler.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'aa-personal-lines-auto',
  templateUrl: './personal-lines-auto.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./personal-lines-auto.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
    const state = navigation.extras.state as {
      stateGroup: string,
    };
    this.stateGroup = state.stateGroup;
  }

  routeA: routeA;
  routeB: routeB;
  routeC: routeC;
  routeD: routeD;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.stateGroup == "GroupA") {
      this.routeA.setNext(this.routeB.setNext(this.routeC));
    }
    else {
      this.routeA.setNext(this.routeD.setNext(this.routeC));
    }
  }
}

class routeA extends AbstractHandler {
  public handle(request: string): string {
    if (request === "true") {
      return `{request}`;
    }
    return super.handle(request);
  }
}

class routeB extends AbstractHandler {
  public handle(request: string): string {
    if (request === "true") {
      return `{request}`;
    }
    return super.handle(request);
  }
}

class routeC extends AbstractHandler {
  public handle(request: string): string {
    if (request === "true") {
      return `{request}`;
    }
    return super.handle(request);
  }
}

class routeD extends AbstractHandler {
  public handle(request: string): string {
    if (request === "true") {
      return `{request}`;
    }
    return super.handle(request);
  }
}
```

My issue is I am not sure how I would pass the navigation from one component to the next component on a button click.  I would need to go from component routeA to routeB to routeC in one case and then it changes.  Or could simply use html pages without components.  I was also looking at the Ui-Router as a possible solution too.  The routes are much longer and have a lot more variation.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to follow and how to help you without code samples of how it works today and the problem. Just to make sure, you do know you can pass objects (component input) into various components and use if/else to display such component etc?

Comment: Sorry, I added additional information and code.